# python pandas: set value to next row's - only for certain rows (according to condition)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some data frame.
I want to find rows which match a specific condition, and give those rows a value from the following row.

Example:

I have the following df

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"ID":range(1,11), "Label":["ABC","BBC","DAH","ACDC","CBA","DBS","HTG","PPP","HLM","AAA"]})
>>> df
   ID Label
0   1   ABC
1   2   BBC
2   3   DAH
3   4  ACDC
4   5   CBA
5   6   DBS
6   7   HTG
7   8   PPP
8   9   HLM
9  10   AAA
```

I want to change the ID of rows where "Label" contains the letter 'H' to the ID of the following row, so it will look like:

```
>>> df
   ID Label
0   1   ABC
1   2   BBC
2   4   DAH
3   4  ACDC
4   5   CBA
5   6   DBS
6   8   HTG
7   8   PPP
8  10   HLM
9  10   AAA
```

I tried this:

```
df.loc[df["Label"].str.contains("H"),"ID"] =  df[df["Label"].str.contains("H").shift().fillna(False)]["ID"]
```

but it put NaN in the cells instead of the IDs

```
>>> df
     ID Label
0   1.0   ABC
1   2.0   BBC
2   NaN   DAH
3   4.0  ACDC
4   5.0   CBA
5   6.0   DBS
6   NaN   HTG
7   8.0   PPP
8   NaN   HLM
9  10.0   AAA
```

Is there anyway of doing this? preferably in one line (or at least without having to iterate row-by-row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `shift` with `loc`, very similar to your attempt, but somewhat more simple: shift the `ID`s by 1 where `Label` contains `H`.

```
df.loc[df.Label.str.contains('H'),'ID'] = df.ID.shift(-1)
>>> df
     ID Label
0   1.0   ABC
1   2.0   BBC
2   4.0   DAH
3   4.0  ACDC
4   5.0   CBA
5   6.0   DBS
6   8.0   HTG
7   8.0   PPP
8  10.0   HLM
9  10.0   AAA
```